# Tagging friends and place in a image post using Graph-API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to figure out how to tag friends and the location when an media object such as a image has been attached to the post. I understand it's possible to use the "tags" and "location" parameters when posting a message to your own feed (/me/feed), but result differ for posting to /me/photo and unfortunately doesn't work at all. The code snippet below is what I have so far:

```
            var photoIndex = 0;

            var facebookBatchParameters = new List<FacebookBatchParameter>();

            foreach (var photo in photos)
            {
                IDictionary<string, Object> parameters = new ExpandoObject();

                parameters["message"] = message;
                parameters["tags"] = "###, ###";
                parameters["place"] = "###";
                parameters[string.Format("photo{0}", photoIndex++)] =
                    new FacebookMediaObject {ContentType = "image/jpeg", FileName = photo.FileName}.SetValue(
                        photo.Data);

                facebookBatchParameters.Add(new FacebookBatchParameter
                    {
                        HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
                        Path = "/me/photo",
                        Parameters = parameters
                    });
            }

            await App.FacebookClient.BatchTaskAsync(facebookBatchParameters.ToArray());
```